# How can I set focus on first input field on each page in my whole application in angular 6

Tags: angular

My application is in final stages and we have not implemented autofocus on input tags. Now we have a requirement where we wish to put focus on first input tag in each of the page. 
There are lot of pages/forms in my application, so using ViewChild in each component can be a tedious task. 
Hence I'm looking for some way from which I can write some code at one place and it triggers focus on first input on whatever page is loaded. 
Can anyone suggest some way to do this?

Comment: what about the `autofocus` attribute?

Comment: @AJT82 I think OP is looking common logic which finds the first input for every component and sets a focus but without making any change in the component itself.

Comment: @SangramNandkhile is correct. setting an autofocus on first input in each component is a tedious task and it might happen that we miss some thing. So as Sangram said, I'm looking for some common logic. may be some service which runs with angular change detection or compiler and find first input in all the components and puts autofocus. May be how angular compiler detects decorators and puts some code according to that decorator on the class.

Comment: `I'm looking for some common logic. may be some service which runs with angular change detection or compiler and find first input in all the components and puts autofocus. May be how angular compiler detects decorators and puts some code according to that decorator on the class` okay. So have you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: I tried creating one decorator for this but that will still needs to be called in each component. so was thinking if we can have some better solution @AJT82

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subscribe to router events in your app component and if even is instance of navigationEnd means route change occur then get first input on page and focus using jquery
something like below in your app component constructor

```
 router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      if(e instanceof NavigationEnd)
        {
         var ele= $('input[type=text],textarea').filter(':visible:first').focus();
        }
    });
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-guards-9j9yxy)

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a method decorator which would do what you want. That is, if you don't mind to import this function to all pages. You would then simply attach this decorator to the `AfterViewInit` life cycle, like so:

```ts
@setFocus()
ngAfterViewInit() { }
```

The decorator function would then search after the first input field found and if found, set focus to that element:

```ts
export function setFocus(): MethodDecorator {
  return function (target: Object, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      const ele = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0] as HTMLElement;
      if (ele) {
        ele.focus();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqims?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use tabindex property of HTML
element with tabindex="1" will receive focus first

eg:

see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
   :https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/

NB: Be careful using tabindex as it imposes a tab order on the content that bears no resemblance to the expected tab order.